# BNF for Java Input Statements

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bnf, javacc

I am writing a Java source code(.java) to pseudocode generator in Java using JDK 7. I want to display the pseudo code format of input statements as:

```
read n
```

like we see in Pascal.

However the thing is there are myriad ways to take console input in Java. My pseudo code generator is nothing but a parser of Java grammars. However I could not design a grammar to parse input statements.

So can anyone tell me how to write a BNF expression for Java Input Statements.
If my approach is wrong please mention the correct approach.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: @hege_hegedus  I am using javacc which is a parser generator like ANTLR, but my problem is developing the grammar, almost all the grammars I used are available in [Java Language Specification] (download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jls-7-mr3.../JLS-JavaSE7-Full.pdf) but there is no such grammar for input.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. What exactly do you mean by a "grammar to parse input statements"? Are you saying that the grammars you found aren't able to parse a Java program that reads input? Because I find that doubtful. "Input statements" in Java are just method calls and surely the available Java grammars are able to parse method calls.

Comment: @sepp2k definitely my grammars can parse statements and methods but i'm looking for a grammar to exclusively detect input statements. As 
I said it would be used to generate pseudo code.

Comment: @SwagatoChatterjee Do you mean the grammar should reject any statement that does not read input? How would you be able to express anything useful that way. Either way that does not sound like something that should be handled at the grammar level.

Comment: @sepp2k No the grammar should detect input statements such that it could be added to the AST. Later when I shall walk the AST I shall generate the pseudo code for input.

Comment: You say your "generator is nothing but a parser", but parsers and generators do different things. Parsers input members of a languages. Generators output members of a language. So it's not clear what it is you are trying to do.  Also you say you want a BNF for "Java Input Statements", but Java does not have "input statements"; so again it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell The Generator is a combination of a parser and a visitor. The parser builds the AST and the visitor generates the pseudo code. I don't get what you mean by _Java does not have "input statements"_ aren't things like, int k= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();  an input statement.

Comment: @SwagatoChatterjee That makes what you are doing clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you'd like to have Java input like

```
int k = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt() ;
int m = k * 2 ;
k = k + 1 ;
```

turn into psuedo code output like

```
var k
read k
var m := k * 2
k := k + 1
```

There are at least three phases where you might recognize the "input statements". One is during parsing. Another is between parsing and generation (i.e. an analysis phase that transforms or marks the tree). A third is during generation.

Of the three, I'd suggest that the second or third might be best. Parsing is already complex enough.  But if you really want to do it during parsing, you can do it with a combination of semantic and syntactic lookahead.

```
void DeclOrInput() :
{}
{
     LOOKAHEAD( Input() ) Input()
|
     LocalDeclStatement()
}

void Input() :
{  }
{  <NEW>
   LOOKAHEAD({ token(1).image.equals("Scanner") } )
   <ID> 
   "("
   LOOKAHEAD( { token(1).image.equals("System") } ) 
   <ID> 
   "."
   LOOKAHEAD( { token(1).image.equals("in") } )
   <ID> 
   ")" "."
   LOOKAHEAD( { token(1).image.equals( "nextInt" ) } )
   <ID> 
   "(" ")" ";"
}
```

Comment: but what if someone uses BufferedReader, as in, '  int k=Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in)).readLine());  '

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your code,the generated parser has errors.Eclipse is telling me 'tk not resolved'.Why is JavaCC not being able to generate a parser which is not declaring Token tk

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix the compilation problem mentioned by @SwagatoChatterjee